# Will my wiring setup work with the Nest Thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I would like someone who is smarter then me to let me know if this current wiring setup would work with the Nest Thermostat?

Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: Yes, it is compatible.

Comment: Are there unused wires back there?

Comment: Will i need to use a jumper wire to setup the Nest?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [Nest Compatibility Checker](https://nest.com/works/) to be sure. Based on having G, Y, W, R, and a jumpered Rc wire, it looks like your setup is compatible.

Note that Nest has an internal battery and does not require a C (Common) wire, but it is better to have one if you able to add it (with a currently unused wire, for example).